# How to calculate average hours worked from bar graph

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, average-case

I want to calculate average hours worked from below bar graph and following this method but I feel this method is not correct to find average working hours

[image]

Procedure A:

```
( 4*1+4*2 +6*3+7*4 + 13*5 +8*6 ) /(1+2+3+4+5+6)sum of worked hours
average= 171/21 =  8.14
```

procedure B:

```
average= ( 4+4+6+7+13+8)/6( total  green bar counts)
 average= 42/6= 7
```

Can anyone suggest which one is correct way to find average working hours ??

Comment: Try to succinctly, but completely describe the average you want - that should make computing something else less likely. What is the COMPUTER**SCIENCE** angle?

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the above mentioned procedures gives the correct average working hours.
Average working hours is the ratio of the total working hours of employees to the number of employees.
I don't understand the reason for posting this question in this platform it is in no way related to computer science and you could possibily find the answer by a simple search engine query or post the question in Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Comment: (@AndrejBauer: With samples from 1 to 6, any average outside that interval lacks credibility. *average hours worked* is neither *hours worked/abscissa label unit* (what if the graph extends to 24 h?) nor *average number of people/bar(category)*.)